# Unable to get individual data callbacks with net.createConnection();

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, unix-socket

I am a newbie to Node.js concepts. I am studying the use of Unix sockets as a means of communication between C and Node.js.

**In C:** 
I am sending 1000 iterations of a 100 byte long message.

**In Node.js:**
I am receiving 4 data callbacks of size:

- 1st callback: 10000
- 2nd callback: 32200
- 3rd callback: 32200
- 4th callback: 25600

I understand that I am able to receive the complete data. However, how do I get this data in 1000 callbacks each with size 100 bytes (the same way I am sending it).

### Code Reference

**Server in C (Partial):**

```
char buf[100];
int loop_count = 0;
memset(buf,0xA5,sizeof(buf));
while(loop_count < 1000) {
    rc = sizeof(buf);
    if (write(cl, buf, rc) != rc) {
        if (rc > 0) fprintf(stderr,"partial write");
        else {
            perror("write error");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    ++loop_count;
}
```

**Client in Node.js:**

```
var net = require('net');
var client = net.createConnection("temp");
#temp is the socket file name

client.on("connect", function() {
    console.log("Connection established");
});

client.on("data", function(data) {
   console.log("Found data "+data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets buffer data, so while you write blocks of 100 bytes into a socket, a reader won't necessarily read the data in neat 100-byte blocks.

You can use a module like [`block-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/block-stream) to split the data into 100-byte blocks for you:

```
const BlockStream = require('block-stream');
const net         = require('net');
const client      = net.createConnection('temp');
const bs          = new BlockStream(100);

let count = 0;

client.pipe(block).on('data', function(data) {
  count++;
  console.log('Found data: ', data);
}).on('end', function() {
   console.log('Read %s blocks', count);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this resolves this query. However, is there a way to receive in the same way as sent by the sender (even if sizes of each send vary and the size is known to receiver). Like:

[Sender ---> Size of Chunk 'x' over socket 1 -----> Receiver]     
[Sender ---> Chunk of size 'x' over socket 2 ---> Receiver]     
[Sender ---> Size of Chunk 'y' over socket 1 -----> Receiver]      
[Sender ---> Chunk of size 'y' over socket 2 ---> Receiver]     
 
I will be able to program socket 1 based on your suggestion. But how should I proceed with programming socket 2?

Comment: It's a tricky subject, because network data gets buffered by the OS, and during sending it may get split up in relatively arbitrary chunks. A common method of dealing with that is to prefix the block of data you're sending with a header that includes the size of the data; the format (and therefore, the size) of the header is known to both parties, and the receiver knows to expect a block of data of a particular size. But it will require some housekeeping on the receiving side, because one `data` event may contain multiple or partial packets.